# How Can I give Initial value to react-datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-datepicker

I'm using [react-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/)

and here is my code

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// Moment
import moment from 'moment';
// Components
import { TextField } from './Text';
// DatePicker 
import DatePicker, { registerLocale } from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

import ar from 'date-fns/locale/ar-SA';
registerLocale('ar', ar);    

const CustomInput = (props) => {
  const { label, value, helperText, disabled, placeholder, onClick } = props;

  return (<TextField
    size={'lg'}
    label={label}
    value={value}
    disabled={disabled}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    onClick={onClick}
    helperTextErrorMessage={helperText}
  />
);
  }

class DateField extends Component {
    state = {
      startDate: this.props.value
    };
  
    handleChange = startDate => {
      const { name, onChange } = this.props;
      console.log(startDate);
      this.setState({ startDate }, () => {
        if(name) {
          onChange(name, startDate);
        } else {
          onChange(startDate);
        }
      });
    };
  
    render() {
      const {
        name,
        label,
        // value,
        withPortal,
        disabled,
        readOnly,
        required,
        children,
        dateFormat,
        helperText,
        placeholder,
        isClearable,
        closeOnSelect,
        showTimeSelect,
        showPopperArrow,
        showWeekNumbers,
        showMonthDropdown,
      } = this.props;

      return (
        <DatePicker
          name={name}
          locale={'ar'}
          // value={value}
          id={`${name}-date-picker`}
          disabled={disabled}
          readOnly={readOnly}
          required={required}
          withPortal={withPortal}
          dateFormat={dateFormat}
          isClearable={isClearable}
          placeholderText={placeholder}
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          showTimeSelect={showTimeSelect}
          showPopperArrow={showPopperArrow}
          showWeekNumbers={showWeekNumbers}
          shouldCloseOnSelect={closeOnSelect}
          showMonthDropdown={showMonthDropdown}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          // override Input
          customInput={<CustomInput { ...this.props } />}
          // Override Popper
          // popperClassName="some-custom-class"
          popperPlacement="top-right"
          popperModifiers={{
            offset: {
              enabled: true,
              offset: "50px, 10px"
            },
            preventOverflow: {
              enabled: true,
              escapeWithReference: false,
              boundariesElement: "viewport"
            }
          }}
        />
      );
    }
  }

DateField.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  helperText: PropTypes.string,
  dateFormat: PropTypes.string,
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  
  children: PropTypes.any,

  required: PropTypes.bool,
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  readOnly: PropTypes.bool,
  withPortal: PropTypes.bool,
  isClearable: PropTypes.bool,
  closeOnSelect: PropTypes.bool,
  showTimeSelect: PropTypes.bool,
  showWeekNumbers: PropTypes.bool,
  showPopperArrow: PropTypes.bool,
  showMonthDropdown: PropTypes.bool,

  onChange: PropTypes.func
};

DateField.defaultProps = {
  label: '',
  helperText: '',
  placeholder: '',
  dateFormat: 'yyyy/MM/dd',

  disabled: false,
  readOnly: false,
  required: false,
  withPortal: false,
  isClearable: true,
  closeOnSelect: true,
  showTimeSelect: false,
  showPopperArrow: false,
  showWeekNumbers: false,
  showMonthDropdown: false,

  onChange() {}
};

export { DateField };
```

from my understanding that when the date changes i assign the new value to the state and when i logged the date value i found it in ISO format like this

```
'Wed Jul 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)'
```

but i want to set a `default value` to the datepicker from outside in order to update the component if there is a value as following

```js
<DateField 
  name={FormFields.DATE_OF_BIRTH}
  label={strings.dateOfBirth}
  placeholder={strings.chooseDateOfBirth}
  value={'Tue Jul 28 2020 03:27:18 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)'}
/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

it gives me an error which is
[image]

`plz note` that is the value from outside and the changed date from picker itself are the `same`

So How To Pass a value to the picker?

**UPDATE**

i solved it by passing the value normally then in the component i converted the value to date object because the picker expects it

```js
    state = {
      startDate: null
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      const { value } = this.props;

      if(value) {
        this.setState({ startDate: moment(value).toDate() });
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the constructor in your DateField Class

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSignUp = this.handleSignUp.bind(this);
    this.state = {startDate: props.value};
  }
```

Comment: thanks For Your Response, this is not the issue, i solved it and i'll update the question